# php streams do not timeout

Tags: php, sockets

Following Andrey's example [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php#Hcom44501) I tried to make a [stream socket server](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php) to serve multiple clients.

```
$master = array();
$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:8000", $errno, $errstr);
if (!$socket) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $master[] = $socket;
    while (1) {
        $read = $write= $master;
        $mod_fd = stream_select($read, $write, $_e = NULL, 5);
        if ($mod_fd === FALSE) {
            break;
        }
        foreach ($read as $readStream) {
            if ($readStream === $socket) {
                $conn = stream_socket_accept($socket);
                stream_set_blocking($conn, 0);
                stream_set_timeout($conn, 5);
                $master[] = $conn;
             }
        foreach ($this->master as $x) {
            var_dump(socket_get_status($x));
           }
        }
    }
}
```

But the streams never timeout, even if I pull the network cable out of a client there is no `eof` flag or `timed_out` flag set.

The output is always:

```
array(7) {
  ["stream_type"]=>
  string(14) "tcp_socket/ssl"
  ["mode"]=>
  string(2) "r+"
  ["unread_bytes"]=>
  int(0)
  ["seekable"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["timed_out"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["blocked"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["eof"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Note: I'm running this php from the command prompt with `$>php test.php`

**Edit:**

I found a possible answer [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php#100676) why its not working but I tried:

```
socket_set_option($conn, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec'=>5, 'usec'=>0));
```

as suggested, but this did not make any difference

Comment: Did you find find a solution ?

Comment: @Ahmad It seems that under some circumstances, eg, network cable pulled out, the socket server is unable to detect the disconnection. My workaround in the end was to poll the receiving end with a message periodically and if the expected response was not received then I would remove the socket from the master array.

Comment: Actually what you have mentioned in your comment is the correct way to detect the lost connections, I have the same issue but I made that: stream_set_timeout($socket, 0, 300); before fwrite (write buffer method), Taking into account that timeout may extend to minute or greater than that, after timeout if the data wasn't been sent fwrite method will display a warning that data wasn't sent. And its return will be FALSE, so you can make: if($fwrite === false){ removeSocket($socket); }